# PHP to reload page from modal

Tags: php, modal-dialog

i am trying to reload page using onClick="location.href='Edit_Equip.php?txtidforsite='" /> but i get Notice: Undefined variable: id
i have tried to define id but still get errors any help would be great

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');
    if(isset($_POST['txtidforsite']))
    {
        $id=$_POST['txtidforsite'];
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $query3 = mysql_query("UPDATE ftn_site_equip SET siteidequip='".$_POST['txtidforsite']."', patype='".$_POST['txtpa']."', drxtype='".$_POST['txtdrx']."' WHERE siteidequip='$id'");
            if($query3)
            {
                header('refresh:2; url=#openModa3');
            }
        }
        $query1=mysql_query("select * from ftn_site_equip where siteidequip='$id'");
        $query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1);
?>

        <form method="post" action="" align="center">    
        <input name="txtidforsite" value="<?php echo $query2['siteidequip']; ?>" size="36" class="siteinfotable"/>     
        <input name="txtdrx" value="<?php echo $query2['drxtype']; ?>" size="36" class="siteinfotable"/>     
        <input name="txtpa" value="<?php echo $query2['patype']; ?>" size="36" class="siteinfotable"/>     
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="update_record_button" value="Update Record" onclick="window.location='#openModal2';" />    
        </form>     
<?php
    }
?>
<div id="openModal" class="cancel_modal">
    <div align="center">        
        <h2 align="center">Are you sure you want to cancel all changes ?</h2>
        <input name="yes" type="button" value="Yes" class="yes_button" onClick="location.href='Edit_Form.php?txtid='" />
        <input name="no" type="button" value="No" class="no_button" onclick="location.href='#close'"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="openModal2" class="cancel_modal">
    <div align="center">
        <img alt="" src="Images/tick.jpg"/><br/>
        <h2 align="center">Record Successfully Updated</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="openModa3" class="cancel_modal">
    <div align="center">        
        <h2 align="center">What Next ?</h2>
        <input name="yes" type="button" value="Retrun to Site Information" class="yes_button" onClick="location.href='Edit_Equip.php?txtidforsite=<?php echo $id; ?>'" />
        <input name="no" type="button" value="Search for Another Site" class="no_button" onclick="location.href='search.php'"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please use $_GET['txtidforsite'] instead of $_POST['txtidforsite']

Comment: use this $id=$_GET['txtidforsite']; i hope its working for you.

Comment: If i use _POST my php form appears on the page if i use _GET my page is blank?

Comment: please change query string txtidforsite to onClick="location.href='Edit_Equip.php?edit_id=<?php echo $id; ?>'" and this like 
$id=$_GET['edit_id'];

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i still get undefined error, i will keep playing with the code

Comment: Try putting your PHP code below all the HTML code? Tell me if that works

Comment: Mysql has been deprecated http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php. Please use `mysqli` or `PDO`. Also passing `post` values directly in queries is dengraous for your site. It does not prevent sql injection